# Unable to see whole world map by decreasing panzoom bar?

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap, open-source-gis

I am seeing one weird thing in Openlayers today. I am unable to see whole map by using panzoombar, previously i used to.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>OpenLayers Example</title>
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div style="width:100%; height:100%" id="map"></div>
      <script defer="defer" type="text/javascript">
       var  Geographic  = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"); 
       var  Mercator = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");

       var map = new OpenLayers.Map({
           div: "map",
           projection: Mercator,
           displayProjection: Geographic,
           center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(0, 0),
           minResolution: "auto",
           minExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-1, -1, 1, 1),
           maxResolution: "auto",
           maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-180, -90, 180, 90),
           units : 'km'

       });

       var layerOSM = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
       map.addLayer(layerOSM);
       map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
       map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(0, 0), 1);
       map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar());

      </script>

</body>
</html>
```

this is the code, panzoombar is showing all the levels, but it stopped at last above two levels and not coming down.

Comment: Whats the problem. Is it the Openlayers problem?

Comment: Does this happen in other browsers?  Is your browser zoomed in too far?  Try pressing ctrl+0

Comment: Yes it is happening in all browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this is all about div size. openlayers automatically makes its minimum zoom level to fit it to whole world map... and this does not seem as a problem.

it makes people that "you can see the whole world at this zoom level and i dont want you to see blank images with decreasing the level of zoom."

**when width and height is 100% or 600px,400px**:

it makes automatically  min zoom level to : 3

[image: openlayers]

**when width: 200px and height: 400px :**

it makes automatically  min zoom level to : 1

[image]

you can test it with changing the div width and height...

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Thank you very much @Aragon, But i want to show the map with width 100% and height 100%. How can i do it.

Comment: this is not a problem if you think so use OpenLayers 2.10 library. http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.10/lib/OpenLayers.js Dont forget to add missing libraries as OpenLayers.Projection. if not you can get OpenLayers.X is not a constructor...

Comment: the url is broken?

Comment: ok i have fixed the missing url link...

Comment: Hi can u give me where can i get missing libraries..

Comment: you can check out them under the same link as http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.10/lib/OpenLayers/ and dont forget to add them in OpenLayers.js ...jsfiles = new Array("OpenLayers/Util.js")

Comment: Hi @Aragon even after adding everything the map is not displaying.. can u suggest me..

Comment: Sorry i am so busy i Will check it soon

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4171/discussion-between-aragon-and-ramesh-k)