# OpenLayers: constraint a map extent and fit a div

Tags: openlayers-2, file-size

I need to display a map with a world extension -18,-90,180,90. I want the map on the initial view to fit in the div. I tried to define the div proportionally to the map extent, but it does not work: the map displays vector before lon=-180° and after lon=180°.

I tried to define a maxExtent and restrictedExtent in the map, but it does not work (see image). How can I force the map to fit to restrictedExtent AND to the div (or what is the correct div dimension)?

[image: The map extent is larger than restrictedExtent]

Source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
     <title></title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://myip/geoserver/openlayers/theme/default/style.css" type="text/css">
      <style>
     #map-id {width: 800px;
              height: 400px;}
   </style>

   <script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="map-id"></div>

    <script>
      var extent = new OpenLayers.Bounds(-180,-90,180,90);
      var options = {restrictedExtent:extent, maxExtent:extent};

      var map = new OpenLayers.Map("map-id", options);
      var imagery = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
          "Global Imagery",
          "http://maps.opengeo.org/geowebcache/service/wms",
           {layers: "bluemarble", isBaseLayer:false},
           {maxExtent:extent, mapResolution:'auto'}
            );

       var lmes=new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
            "LMEs",
            "http://myip/geoserver/ocean/wms",
            {layers:'ocean:LME66', transparent:true, styles:'LMES_colors'},
            {isBaseLayer:false, opacity:1, singleTile:true, visibility:true, maxExtent:extent, mapResolution:'auto'}
        );
        map.addLayers([lmes, imagery]);
        map.zoomToMaxExtent();       
        map.addControl(info);

        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually understood what was the problem: by default, the WMS is configured to output a singleTile of size 512x256.
If I resized my div to 512x256, then the map would fit. It would fit also with multiples (such as 1024x256).

To force the WMS to spit out a singleTile matching the div, I had to compute the minResolution and maxResolution, and pass them to the map option:

```
var maxResolution = 360/800.0;
var minResolution = 0.5/800.0;
var extent = new OpenLayers.Bounds(-180,-90,180,90);
var options = {restrictedExtent:extent, maxExtent:extent, wrapDateLine:false, minResolution:minResolution, maxResolution:maxResolution,controls: [new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoom()] };
```

<del>This page helped me much: http://simonmercier.net/blog/?p=88</del> *Dead link*

Answer (score 0):

Try out following code it may help but for that you need Jquery library included in your page.

```
  $(window).resize(function () {

         //$('#log').append('<div>Handler for .resize() called.</div>');

         var canvasheight=$('#map-id').parent().css('height');

         var canvaswidth=$('#map-id').parent().css('width');

         $('#map-id').css("height", canvasheight);

         $('#map-id').css("width", canvaswidth);

   });
```

or check out [Unable to see whole world map by decreasing panzoom bar?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29407/unable-to-see-whole-world-map-by-decreasing-panzoom-bar)

Comment: Thanks for that. I guess my problem is related to what I read in the link you provided. Do you know how I can forbid the layer named 'lmes' (colored shapefiles in the image) to display before -180 and after 180? I suppose it would help framing the view

Comment: @BrunovonParis Try add wrapDateLine: false in layer 'lmes' layer attributes after mapResolution:'auto'

Comment: I've just tried: it changes nothing, the shapefile keeps on repeating...